# jQuery Datetimepicker - allow multiple time formats

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am building a form with some datetime fields. I am using the jQuery DateTimePicker plugin to make the form a bit more friendly - http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

I need to allow the user to type the time in multiple formats though. The plugin restricts the user from typing anything in the textbox that is not in the correct format. I need to allow times as 15:10 or 15.10. I don't mind if the picker always spits out 15:10 but I need to allow the user to type decimal points. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the **"."** for a **":"** in the keypress event, see [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/CwPV8/)

Answer (score 0):

In `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js` in `_doKeyPress` make the following small change:

```
        if ($.datepicker._get(inst, 'constrainInput')) {
            var ampm = tp_inst._defaults.ampm,
                dateChars = $.datepicker._possibleChars($.datepicker._get(inst, 'dateFormat')),
                datetimeChars = tp_inst._defaults.timeFormat.toString()
                                        .replace(/[hms]/g, '')
                                        .replace(/TT/g, ampm ? 'APM' : '')
                                        .replace(/Tt/g, ampm ? 'AaPpMm' : '')
                                        .replace(/tT/g, ampm ? 'AaPpMm' : '')
                                        .replace(/T/g, ampm ? 'AP' : '')
                                        .replace(/tt/g, ampm ? 'apm' : '')
                                        .replace(/t/g, ampm ? 'ap' : '') + 
                                        " " + tp_inst._defaults.separator +
                                        tp_inst._defaults.timeSuffix +
                                        (tp_inst._defaults.showTimezone ? tp_inst._defaults.timezoneList.join('') : '') +
                                        (tp_inst._defaults.amNames.join('')) + (tp_inst._defaults.pmNames.join('')) +
                                        ':*' +
                                        dateChars,
                chr = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode === undefined ? event.keyCode : event.charCode);
            return event.ctrlKey || (chr < ' ' || !dateChars || datetimeChars.indexOf(chr) > -1);
        }
```

I've added `':*' +` to support entering `:` and `*` as time separators too.

On timepicker init use:

$('#rest_example_1').timepicker({
        ...
    timeFormat: 'hh.mm tt'
});

The `dot` b/w hh and mm is very important ... tt - optional ... but default setting is 'hh:mm tt' so it's good to use 'hh.mm tt' which is a bit similar.

More or less this works.